# Is my computer password making me vulnerable?

Tags: security, macbook-pro

My macbook pro can be stolen while I'm traveling in LATAM, Africa, Asia or somewhere else.

1-If my computer is stolen, can they brute force to find my computer password?

I am thinking since they can enter input **only** by touching the keyword, they can't brute force. But idk for sure.

2-I am assuming there's no way to remotely brute force to find my computer password. That's true, right?

I don't appear like someone important or rich so I'm guessing they wouldn't try so hard to find the computer pw but idk. Disk is encrypted with filevault.

If 1 & 2 don't work against me, I can even be safe with a password of 3 letters.

Comment: A 3 character password is NOT secure.

Answer (score 2):

Security is a matter of degrees.

You wouldn't install a 10 million dollar bank vault & secure it with a 10 buck cycle lock.
Same for FileVault protected by a three letter password.
For the sake of half a dozen or so extra characters - a mere second to type - you'd make their task closer & closer to impossible with each additional character.

Someone determined enough will attempt to brute force it, no matter how complex your password, if they determine the contents once unlocked worth the effort.
Conversely, a casual opportunist thief would probably only be concerned with selling it on & wouldn't care about the data on it, so long as they can make it look saleable. They might have a poke at some easy passwords - bonus for them if they can get in.

If your Mac doesn't have a T2 chip, they can just wipe it & sell it. T2 will prevent that, so long as you have Find My activated [even if it can't connect].